# Algorithm/Graphs: Maintain sets

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

In an application, I'm reading in the vertices of an undirected graph one-by-one, the edges becoming apparent only when both vertices have appeared.

After parsing, I need to quickly iterate the connected components of the graph one-by-one. What would be my algorithm of choice to build up the connected components **at parse time**? (At parse time because it's rather expensive to list the edges).

I have 250 vertices and it's hard to tell the number of edges per vertice, but let's say it's limited by 100 (that is, we have << 250 * 100 / 2 = 12500 edges altogether). I'd also like to know how a lower edge count (let's say 500) would affect the choice of the algorithm. (Yes, 250 vertices is not much, but in this application, even small speedups count--the algorithm runs many times).

Comment: Haven't given it much thought but a couple ideas:
1) Caching
2) Union find.

Have you considered either of those?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that come to my mind is some enhanced "union-find" algorithm.
For basics please take a look at [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) about it or it was presented by ROBERT SEDGEWICK on the latest Coursera's course "Algorithms, Part1" - it was during "Week 1: Union-Find". Please view the class [archive](https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-002/) (you can sign-up for free). 
On slide 45 of the week 1 you have the summary of worst-case times for basic and enhanced versions of this algorithm.